# Trying to add file to new MSI Feature-> Component in Installshiled

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

Hello I have created a basic MSI using snapshot for learning purposes and I'm adding new folders and filesetc. The problem I'm having is I want to add a file to an existing folder [InstallDIR]. I keep getting this error

Replacing file 'C:\Packages\My App\MSI_Package\program files\My App\LaunchHello.cmd' with 'C:\Packages\My App\MSI_Package\program files\My App\LaunchHello.cmd'.
ISDEV : Error while copying file: 'C:\Packages\My App\MSI_Package\program files\My App\LaunchHello.cmd'. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Replacing file 'C:\Packages\My App\MSI_Package\program files\My App\ThirdAtt.txt' with 'C:\Packages\My App\MSI_Package\program files\My App\ThirdAtt.txt'.
ISDEV : Error while copying file: 'C:\Packages\My App\MSI_Package\program files\My App\ThirdAtt.txt'. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Save completed with 2 error(s).

I have tried to see if this file is locked in some way in servers sessions but I couldn't see anything? I have tried a few different files with the same result.

I can easily add a new feature-> component with a different folder location and I can save without issue for example adding a file under [USERPROFILE]. It seems as soon as I want to add to an existing location it thinks the file is locked? I have also tried adding the file to the existing component that adds files to the [installdir] but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You must save the file to a different location than where the file will reside in the MSI folder structure. In other words it is trying to add a file that already exists in that folder. Create a source folder and import through Installsheild.